# Select only the options that are related to another model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a student/school app with Django + Django Rest Framework in which a student can belong to only one school and can choose Course options for that School they're in.

Currently, I'm doing it the wrong way by having the `course` field at `Student` relate do `Course`, which will of course provide the entire list of courses in my app.

What I'd like my app to be able to do is **select only from courses that that school have added as their courses**. How to do that?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course) # change 'Course' for ???
```

Comment: You need to set the queryset on the form field dynamically for that, can you show your form class?

Comment: not really using forms, I'm using Django Rest Framework. Does it help if I show you serializers, viewsets, etc?

Comment: Yes, please share the serializer and viewsets, etc.

Comment: added serializers and viewsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although if we want to add this like a constraint level on the database it is a bit difficult we can easily set it such that the serializer would not allow you to set incorrect values by specifying the queryset of the field:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Course.objects.all()) # all objects for now
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['course'].queryset = instance.school.courses.all()
```

**Note**: You may need to do also set the queryset in case the update can change the students school.